# Ionic 5 angular back navigation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I have an app in Ionic 5 using Angular in which I need to programmatically navigate from the current page to the previous page. I tried using:

```
this._location.back();
```

and it works but doesn't triggers the back navigation animation like when you navigate with `<ion-back-button>`, it just switches pages. So the question is how can you programmatically navigate back on an Ionic 5 app with Angular, in a way similar to what `<ion-back-button>` does?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
constructor(private navController: NavController){}

 this.navController.back();
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I read that Ionic 5 won't be using `NavController` anymore and you should use Angular router instead but I guess it still works.

Comment: it's doesn't work on me , why ?

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is correct. As stated by the developers of Ionic here:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20448#issuecomment-586288155

it is still save to use the NavController (in combination with angular routing) and this will not be deprecated in future. The documentation on this is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

constructor(private location : Location){}

this.location.back();
```

Common package for Location used this type in back page.